# How Do I Add CSS Class to body Element in Meteor?

Tags: html, css, meteor

I'm starting a Meteor project and I want to use different body css classes on different pages. If I add a css class to body I get:

```
Attributes on <body> not supported
```

The only way I've found is adding the class using JS. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: or use the Js or create wrapper for each page

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard practice is to set body class in respective path hooks:

```
Router.map(function() {

  this.route('someRoute', {
    path: '/someAddress',

    onBeforeAction: function() {
      $('body').addClass('someRouteBodyClass');
      this.next();
    },

    onStop: function() {
      $('body').removeClass('someRouteBodyClass');
    },

    ...
  };

});
```

Comment: @Hubert what if you want to this for all routes?

Comment: You can use controllers and extend them. For example: `ClassController = RouteController.extend({onBeforeAction: ..., onStop: ...});`, then in the map: `this.route('someRoute', {controller: ClassController})`.

Comment: You might need to add this.next(); at the end of onBeforeAction.

Comment: You can also use a `Template.body` helper as suggested in this post, to do it the "Meteor" way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994859/change-body-class-based-on-url-in-meteor

Comment: @oskare: you're right. This wasn't necessary at the time the answer was originally posted, though :-)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution which uses router is great. There's also a solution for setting body class for the whole app:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
   $('body').addClass('classes-for-body');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is especially helpful for situations where you aren't using a router.

Answer (score 2):

You can also perform the actions in the template "rendered" and "destroyed" callbacks.

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function(){
    $('body').addClass('my-class');
}

Template.myTemplate.destroyed = function(){
    $('body.my-class').removeClass('my-class');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `FlowRouter` it work with:

```
FlowRouter.group({
  prefix: '/admin',
  triggersEnter: [function() {
    $('body').addClass('admin-layout');
  }],
  triggersExit: [function() {
    $('body').removeClass('admin-layout');
  }],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always do the style in each html page. not a best practise. but, it works. :D

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go to add a class depending on the route you are on :

```
var currentCategory = new ReactiveVar();
Router.onAfterAction(function() {
    var categoryName = Router.current().options.route._path.split('/')[1];
    currentCategory.set(categoryName);
});
Template.mainLayout.helpers({
    currentCategory: function() {
        return currentCategory.get();
    }
});
```

--

```
<template name="mainLayout">
  <body class='{{currentCategory}}'>
</body>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this adds a second `<body>` element to the document, which isn't quite ideal…

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use to add body class to only homepage.

```
Router.route('/', {
name: 'landing',
onAfterAction: function() {
    setTitle();
},
onBeforeAction: function(){
    $('body').addClass('home');
    this.next();
},
onStop: function() {
  $('body').removeClass('home');
}});
```