# Writing properties or event on the <body> are not allow

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Why in `meteor` if you write on the body any kind of event or property like `style=""` or `onload` you get an error of

```
While Building the application:
client/html/root/yourapp.html:22: Attributes on <body> not supported
```

if it's because any security concern what security concern?, if not about security why its meteor forcing the developers to maintain the `<body>` tag clean.

Previous research:
[How Do I Add CSS Class to body Element in Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382531/css-class-in-body-with-meteor) dont explain why its not allow.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2561 but neither its well explain.

Comment: Allowing it complicate things (what if two different bodies set the same attribute to different values?), and is there really a use case for it (which can't be achieved by using a div instead)?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, but what about `Template.body`?

Comment: @kyll I dont want to use it I was playing with it and saw this message and intrigued me, why meteor can have two bodies?