# Change Body Class Based On URL in Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteor-helper

I have a template named **layout** in my app. Inside has:

```
<body id="body class="{{blue}}>
```

Basically what I want to achieve is that when you hit a url, for example, www.abc.com/sky, I want to add a body class of blue:

```
<body id="body class="blue">
```

In my **client** folder I have this but seems not to work:

```
Template.layout.helpers({
  blue: function() {
    var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
    if(/sky/.test(loc)) {
    $('#body').addClass('blue');
    }
  }
});
```

I am new to the javascript world and I am following a tutorial but the tutorial was not aimed for Meteor.

Comment: Are you using iron router?

Comment: Hi @DavidWeldon yes I am.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shold modify DOM elememts in [onRendered](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) like this:

```
Template.layout.onRendered(function() {
  // get the current route name (better than checking window.location)
  var routeName = Router.current().route.getName();

  // add the class to body if this is the correct route
  if (routeName === 'myRoute')
    $('body').addClass('blue');
});

Template.layout.onDestroyed(function() {
  // remove the class to it does not appear on other routes
  $('body').removeClass('blue');
});
```

---

An alternative (and probably easier) solution is just to use a helper on your `body` template:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  klass: function() {
    if (Router.current().route.getName() === 'myRoute') {
      return 'blue';
    }
  }
});
```

Then your `body` could look like this:

```
<body class="{{klass}}"></body>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. The last option was best as the top does not like to be reactive.

Comment: The `{{klass}}` in my html seems to only work when it is actually inside the body tag....

Comment: `Router.current().route.path()` worked for me. (`Router.current().route.getName()` didn't)

Answer (score 0):

I too needed this feature and found the same issue as @phocks in that `{{klass}}` only works *inside* and not on the body tag. I'm new at Meteor but here's my approach that just uses some jQuery:

```
Template.body.onRendered(function(){
    var instance = this;
    instance.autorun(function() {
        FlowRouter.watchPathChange();
        var context = FlowRouter.current();
        // this does the trick, below
        $('body').attr('class', '').addClass(context.route.name);   

        // this is just to do more CSS stuff if they're logged in
        if(Meteor.userId()){
            $('body').addClass('logged-in');   
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('logged-in');   
        }
    });
});
```

I use this in a `body.js` file, and this code relies on FlowRouter. On path changes, I get the `name` I declared for the route, remove any previous route names from the body tag, then add the current route's name.

As a small side note, I also add a class of `logged-in` to the body for authenticated users, so that's what the bottom few lines are doing.