# Can't set body class with Template.helpers

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

To add dynamic class for body tag i used:

```
<body class="{{bodyClass}}"><!-- this remains uncompiled -->
  {{bodyClass}} <!-- this renders to "blue" -->
</body>
```

and helper code:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  bodyClass: function(){
    return 'blue';
  }
});
```

As result `{{bodyClass}}` Inside body content is compiled to `blue` as expected,
but the `<body class="{{bodyClass}}">` remains uncompiled.

[edit] Ps. I'm using lates meteor 1.3

Comment: shouldn't it be body class={{bodyClass}} without the quotes ?

Comment: @NikhileshKV removing quotes resulted in "Parse error in tag...". My code was based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994859/change-body-class-based-on-url-in-meteor/34860941#34860941 accepted answer from this thread.

Comment: Oops. Yeah just had a look. Not sure what is the problem then.

Comment: @NikhileshKV thanks for having a look anyway. Ps. tried with registerHelper, and single ' quotes, but same result every time.

Comment: Your code will work for templates you define, but not for `Template.body`.

Answer (score 1):

Try onRendered with jQuery addClass

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function (){
    $('body').addClass('blue')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the template right at the begging (or anywhere in the template really) you can simply do:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body: blue;
</style>
```

Use !important if you need to.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip, but changing the body background was only the example for a bigger thing - accessing body className attribute in the easiest way to implement namespaces like page-home, page-user, through changing body attribute.

Comment: Gotchya. I used this when I needed a quick fix on a template I knew would always have a particular background.